# Replace "&" (ampersand) with ";" (semicolon) in URL

Tags: php

I know what you will going to tell me, but for learning purpose I need to know how to change the `&` in URL with `;` using PHP.

**For Example**:

I have a URL like

```
http://example.com/index.php?show=products&index=20&page=5
```

It will become

```
http://example.com/index.php?show=products;index=20;page=5
```

I saw this on [ESPN Cricinfo](http://espncricinfo.com) like they use it for their stats, commentary, like [this](http://www.espncricinfo.com/county-cricket-2014/engine/match/692935.html?innings=4;page=2;view=commentary) page uses it.

As I think, we use `$_GET['...']` to get values from URL in PHP, but this method may use some other string functions.

I already said, if you know how then tell me how. It is only for learning purpose.

Comment: Why are you tagging this question javascript if you want to do the replacement in PHP ?

Comment: Sorry it was my fault

Comment: Does this question needs a regex?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set this option globally inside the *php.ini* file:

```
arg_separator.input = ";"
```

or locally for your current script execution with [`ini_set`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.ini-set.php):

```
ini_set('arg_separator.input', ';');
```

*From the docs:*

> `arg_separator.input string`
>
> List of separator(s) used by PHP to parse input URLs into variables.

The option can receive a character set of possible separators, so if you need to make PHP parsing arguments both with semicolon and ampersand as a separator, set it equal to `;&`.

Additionally [`arg_separator.output`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.arg-separator.output) can be used to separate arguments in PHP generated URLs.

**REF:** http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.arg-separator.input

Comment: @lobner Correct, if you want to set the setting locally from and for the current PHP script only: `ini_set('arg_separator.input', ';');`.

Comment: @user3599534 Check `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` if the setting was set correctly.

Comment: @user3599534 Depending on your configuration it may require server restart to make it working. Otherwise, the current option value should be displayed in the `phpinfo` output. Don't forget that `ini_set` approach will set the option only for the execution of the script where this method was called.